# Open file dialog with image instead of button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I open an file dialogue on image click? 
Additionally, I want to display the "selected files" after selecting the file.
Can someone help me out?

Note - I don't want "choose your file" button, but I want "no item selected text"

```
<div class="attachment">
  <label for="file-input">
    <img class="attachmentImage" src="../../../../assets/Notification Panel/Actions icons/attachment.svg"/>
  </label>
  <input type="file"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have an invisible input field to trigger upon image click with HTML and jQuery:

```js
$("input[id='input_image']").click(function() {
    $("input[id='input_file']").click();
});
// jQuery Solution for Showing Uploaded Image
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#input_image')
                .attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="image" id="input_image" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg" width="30px" />
<!-- onchange="readURL(this);" is for jQuery Solution for Showing Uploaded Image-->
<input type="file" id="input_file" style="display: none" onchange="readURL(this);" />
```

The [height](https://api.jquery.com/height/) and [width](https://api.jquery.com/width/) are set based on the size of the button. To change the lengths, you can set them with jQuery.

Comment: thank you for your solution but i am not able see the selected image .

Comment: @AkashNevagi Sorry, I have added a jQuery solution.

Comment: @AkashNevagi You can set the image size to a set size with jQuery or the default size of image
[HEIGHT](https://api.jquery.com/height/)
[WIDTH](https://api.jquery.com/width/)

Answer (score 1):

try using custom input file:

```js
 function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#profile-img-tag').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        $("#file").change(function(){
            readURL(this);
        });
```

```html
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" placeholder="Enter Your Password" name="files" value="files" style="display: none;">
      <label class="upload_photo" for="file" style="background-color: red; padding: 20px; border-radius: 50%;"></label>
      <img src="" id="profile-img-tag" width="200px" />

    </div>
```